# How do I use the manyToMany relationship in a graphene scheme?

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-django

I'm trying to do a graphql query in django. I have a problem with the manuToManu relationship. Can I ask for help? I don't know where I go wrong.

**Part written in Python**

*models.py*

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Pizza(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
```

*schema.py*

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    pizza = graphene.List(PizzaType)
    topping = graphene.List(ToppingType)

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_pizza(parent, info):
        return Pizza.objects.all()

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_topping(parent, info):
        return Topping.objects.all()
```

*types.py*

```
class ToppingType(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = graphene.NonNull(graphene.Int)
    name = graphene.NonNull(graphene.String)

class PizzaType(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = graphene.NonNull(graphene.Int)
    name = graphene.NonNull(graphene.String)
    toppings = graphene.List(ToppingType)
```

**Part written in Graphql**

*query graphql*

```
query {
  pizza{
    name
    toppings {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

*response graphql*

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "User Error: expected iterable, but did not find one for field PizzaType.toppings."
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "pizza": [
      {
        "name": "mafia",
        "toppings": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a custom resolver for **`toppings`** in **`PizzaType`** class

```
class PizzaType(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = graphene.NonNull(graphene.Int)
    name = graphene.NonNull(graphene.String)
    toppings = graphene.List(ToppingType)

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_toppings(pizza, *args, **kwargs):
        return pizza.toppings.all()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the good answer. I tried to do something like this, but did not provide such params in the method